# two for loops in js. cannot work on nested for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I'm working on a problem below, but not sure why my second for loop does console.log anything. I currently get a result, [], and when I work on loops I sometimes confused because the output returns empty result. So why my second for loop is not executed and why I'm not able to push the result to result array?

> Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.You can return the answer in any order.

> Example 1:
> Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
> Output: [0,1]
> Output: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].

```
function a(nums, target) {

let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < nums.length -1; i++){


    let firstNum = nums[i];

    console.log(i)
    
    for (let j = i + 1; j < nums.length -1; j++){

        console.log(j)
        let secondNum = nums[j];
        
        let sum = firstNum + secondNum;
        
        

        if (sum === target) {
            return result.push(i, j);
            }
        } 
    }
    return result; 
};

a([2,7,11,15], 9)
```

Comment: you are getting two console.logs ... one for i and one for j - so both console.logs happen once each - `return result.push(i, j);` means that you return the new length of results after the push (in this case 2) - and exit the function (since you return) - wat you want to do is remove that return and you'll be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push return only the length of the array, try like below,

```
function a(nums, target) {

    let result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){


        let firstNum = nums[i];

        console.log("i", i)

        for (let j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++){

            console.log("j", j)
            let secondNum = nums[j];

            let sum = firstNum + secondNum;



            if (sum === target) {
                result.push(i, j);
                return result;
            }
        } 
    }
    return result; 
};

let result = a([2,7,11,15], 9);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this will still stop the process early - I believe the intent is to find all combinations that satisfy the condition ... i.e. no return required inside the loops

Comment: But the question is, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target

Comment: in this case there is one solution ... what if the target was achievable in two ways - that's the only reason I can think to push to an array :p - I'm not criticising your answer though - I read the intent differently, that's all - I mean, you could just `return [i, j]`, right :p

Comment: @zzzzou the iterations for `j` loop must go till `j < nums.length` and not till `j < nums.length -1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually correct except for the fact that you are returning the result of `result.push(i, j)` which returns the length of the array.

Use `result.push(i, j);` and then `return result;`

Instead of just `return result.push(i, j);`

Answer (score 0):

Consider breaking the problem down into smaller parts -

- `t` generates unique combinations of numbers
- `a` steps thru the generator searching for the first valid solution

```js
function* t(n, i = 0, p = [])
{ if (p.length >= 2)
    yield p
  else if (i >= n.length)
    return
  else
    ( yield* t(n, i + 1, [...p, n[i]])
    , yield* t(n, i + 1, p)
    )
}

function a(n, q)
{ for (const [a, b] of t(n)) // <- step thru t
    if (a + b == q)          // <- simple condition
      return [a, b]          // <- solution
}

const result =
  a([2,7,11,15], 9)

console.log(result)
```

Output -

```js
[2, 7]
```

`a` will return `undefined` if the answer cannot be reached